# How do I get Broadcom drivers to be recognized Ubuntu during setup from Windows installer?

Tags: broadcom

I downloaded the newest version of Ubuntu from the site and chose the windows installer version so that I could duel boot and do some speed comparisons. The instillation went well until it told me to restart. I chose the Ubuntu option from the startup and then the loading screen came up and it froze. I shutdown and tried again and chose to do a graphics safe startup thinking it was my graphics card. I was interested to see that at the end of the check list a network card failure and a website. http://wireless.Kernel.org/en/user/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware. I looked into the site and found the firmware I need but I have no input as to how to install it without being able to access Ubuntu directly. I am running Windows XP 64 natively if this is a problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the article referenced in http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 you can see the instructions to install your firmware

From a Terminal window run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

This should be enough to solve your problem

**Edit**: I am assuming you can install this firmware from the cd / iso